Diet-considering app for aspiring nutritionists, children, learners, and shoppers
I am looking for the following Android app:
I am looking for a diet following applications for aspiring nutritionists, children, students, learners, and people with family people with various conditions or on a diet, who must shop, or monitor dieta for them.
The user can select each person's profile. As medical conditions may change, they may also keep a history, of diet-related details, for each condition.
Here are the diet-related details
In the upper left hand corner:

What they must eat

In the lower left hand corner:

A summary with histograms of all the nutrients they are getting and if they are not getting some in the dirt a comment section in each area of why they must avoid it

In the upper right hand corner:

Diet break-ings (for insurance, the person chooses to eat something not on the diet, and the person taking the other person into consideration or shopping for them must respect them. Thus, a list of nutrients not on the diet that the person is eating.

In the lower right hand corner:

A list of consequences, for the diet break-ings (listed as comments, even, in relations to the extra things eaten (that were not on the diet).

On a separate application page:
A calendar with quantity monitoring (for each nutrient) must also be provided (in relation to reach consumed item, as on the CookBook app).
Is there an application like this available anywhere?
Who is willing to develop such an application?
I think it would be very useful.
Thanks.
